# Neo4J: Renaming property keys

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I just got started on Neo & tried to look for prior questions on this topic. I need help to rename one of the property keys.

I created the following node:

```
CREATE (Commerce:Category {title:' Commerce', Property:'Category', Owner:'Magic Pie', Manager:'Simple Simon'})
```

Now want to rename title to name. Is there a way to do it? I don't want to delete the node as there are 100's of nodes with the property "title".

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes, you want to `SET` a new property `name` with the value of the old property `title`. And then `REMOVE` the old property `title`. Something like this...

```
MATCH (c:Category)
WHERE c.name IS NULL
SET c.name = c.title
REMOVE c.title
```

If you have MANY nodes, it is advisable to perform the operation in smaller batches. Here is an example of limiting the operation to 10k at a time.

```
MATCH (c:Category)
WHERE c.name IS NULL
WITH c
LIMIT 10000
SET c.name = c.title
REMOVE c.title
```

Comment: Fascinating fact, but when you pass a query to Neo4j, it loads everything into memory before it performs the operation. This is why the Neo4j browser melts down for a long time when you run monster queries. There is a `cypher shell program` you can get that apparently remedies that, but as mentioned above, it's due to lack of batching.

Answer (score 0):

another solution would be using APOC functions:

```
MATCH (n) WHERE ID(n) = 1234
WITH *, collect(n) AS nodes  // nodes must be converted into a collection first
CALL apoc.refactor.rename.nodeProperty("oldKey ", "newKey", nodes)
// rename doesn't work if the key has strings ^ postfixed in it
YIELD batches, total, timeTaken, committedOperations
RETURN *
```

in the case you accidentially added strings at the end (it's possible during create) the property cannot be accessed via:

```
SET n.newKey = n.oldKey
REMOVE n.oldKey
```

then you must use:

```
SET n.newKey = n.`oldKey `
REMOVE n.`oldKey `
```

this works

Answer (score 0):

And also, just for addition, you can use:

```
SET c.name = c.title, c.title = null
```

instead of

```
SET c.name = c.title
REMOVE c.title
```

People have different views and usages on queries, just use whatever suits you.